# Selecting background url from style attribute with XPATH (and PHP)

Tags: php, dom, xpath, attributes

I'd like to select only the url from this background image style attribute, is that possible with XPATH?

```
 <a href="http://www.test.com" style="background-image: url('http://www.test.com/hello.jpg');">test</a>
```

i have something like

```
$url  = $xpath->query('//a//@style');
```

Comment: And? Does it work? Is it giving you undesired results?

Comment: it will give the full content of the style attribute, I only want to select the content of the url('')

Comment: what's inside the style attribute is no longer part of the DOM, so it's not a job for XPath. You'd find a CSS parser to do that... I'm not aware of a solution for that as common as XPath or DOMDocument, maybe this speficic case is easiest done with a regex.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy, oneliner XPath expression that produces exactly the wanted URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
substring-before(substring-after(@style, "'"),
                 "'"
                )
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     "<xsl:value-of select=
     "substring-before(substring-after(@style, &quot;&apos;&quot;),
                       &quot;&apos;&quot;
                       )
     "/>"
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
 <a href="http://www.test.com" style=
 "background-image: url('http://www.test.com/hello.jpg');">test</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 "http://www.test.com/hello.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrHolder = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@style]') as $node) {
    if (strpos($node->getAttribute('style'), 'background:url') !== FALSE) {

        array_push($arrHolder, $node->tagName . " = " . $node->getAttribute('style'));
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrHolder);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)